# MP3 conversion using Cron?

Tags: mysql, cron, queue

I have created a PHP script that moves WAV files that a user has uploaded via FTP to a temporary directory.   I am having problems running lame.exe when it is accessed via exec so have decided to just run it locally on my VPS and store the source file names and the destination names in a table (for this example called cronmp3).

I am stuck as to where to go next.  I have the queue for files ready in the mysql table, but am not sure how to call them and process them, or what to put in the cron file moving the files is not a problem after conversion, I am able to do that.

Answer (score 0):

To be honest, mysql isn't great for queues. I recommend adding [Redis](http://redis.io/commands#list) to your stack. In php using Predis:

```php
// when the file is uploaded
// add whatever to mysql
// $mysqli->...
// connect to redis
$redis = new Predis\Client();
// add $file to the encodequeue
$redis->call('lpush', 'encodequeue', $file);
```

Then in your cronjob:

```
#!/bin/bash
file=`redis-cli lpop encodequeue`
lame $file -options > output... whatever
```

Comment: I guess I should have picked up based on "wav" and ".exe" in the question that you are on a Windows environment. Good luck. Goooooood luck.

Comment: Hey Joe, no am using Centos mate... just using wine to use Lame to convert as Lame has provided the best quality conversions and most my clients use WAV files.... Thanks for your help!